# How to derive the equation in my question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, oscillators

[image]

How to derive the equation in my question?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78500/2451

Comment: @parkning Qmechanic already derived it for you in his answer to the previous question!

Comment: Sorry，I don't know what he said!

Comment: Take the general [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/78568/6316) made by Qmechanic, look only at the equations $(2),(9),(10)$, and specialize : Take the matrix $B=0$. Take $M$ as a diagonal matrix : $M = Diag(m^\alpha)$. The matrix $K$ corresponds to your matrix $V$. Now equation $(10)$ is exactly your equation.