# Is $H = T + U$ for a pendulum on a circle movement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

I have this problem:

> Obtain Hamilton's equations of motion for a plane pendulum of length $l$ with mass point $m$ whose radius of suspension rotates uniformally on the circumference of a vertical circle of radius $a$.

This is my position vector: 
\begin{equation}
       \vec{r} = (a\cos{(\omega_0 t)} + l\sin{\theta})\hat{\imath} + (a\sin{(\omega_0 t)}-l\cos{\theta})\hat{k}
   \end{equation}
(The angle that describes the movement of the suspension point on the circle is $\omega_0 t$ for being uniform)

From this, using the definition of potential and kinetic energy, the lagrangian is:
\begin{equation}
       L = \frac{m}{2}(a^2\omega_0^2 + 2la\omega_0\dot{\theta}(\sin{(\theta - \omega_0 t)}) + l^2\dot{\theta}^2) - mg(a\sin{(\omega_0 t)}-l\cos{\theta})
   \end{equation}

Now, i tried to make my hamiltonian with the definition 
\begin{equation}
       H = p_i\dot{q_i} - L
   \end{equation}
But... for the problem, i think that this form is useless for the Hamilton equations. Then it occurred to me to use
\begin{equation}
       H = T + U = \frac{m}{2}l^2\dot{\theta}^2 + mg(a\sin{(\omega_0 t)}-l\cos{\theta})
   \end{equation}
However, I'm not sure if I can use it because, according to me, the position vector explicitly depends on time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Some comments: 1. Please note that you haven't actually asked a question except in the title. It's easy to infer what you want to know but please try to make questions as clear and straightforward as possible. 2. The Hamiltonian of a system is not unique and can, in fact, always be made to vanish, cf. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194772/50583. 3. A Hamiltonian depends on positions and generalized momenta. Your expression depends on $\dot(\theta)$. which is neither - how is it supposed to be a Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that, you have to perform a Legendre transformation. Solve for $\dot\theta$,
$$p_{\theta}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\theta}$$
You will get $\dot\theta(p_{\theta})$, i.e. $\dot\theta$ as a function of $p_{\theta}$. Then compute,
$$H = p_{\theta}\dot{\theta}(p_{\theta}) - L(\theta,\dot\theta(p_{\theta}),t)$$
Finally,
$$\dot\theta = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_{\theta}},\quad \dot p_{\theta}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of situation where the Hamiltonian $\sum \dot{q}_ip_i-L$ is not equal to $T+U$.  One can see the problem immediately because
$$
\sum_i \dot{q}_ip_i\ne 2T\, ,
$$
so this system is not a “natural” system.  In fact as written $H$ is not conserved because $L$ depends explicitly in $t$.

The definition
$$
H=\sum \dot{q}_ip_i-L
$$
followed by the elimination of all $\dot{q}_i$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ so that 
$H=H(q,p)$ is correct and the starting point of the analysis.  Hamilton’s equation should be use using $H(q,p)$, not $T+U$.

A related (but different) example is [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166026/36194), although in the latter, $L$ does not depend on $t$ so $H$ is conserved.