# When the hamiltonian isn't equal to energy?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

I have the following hamiltonian:

$$H = \frac{p_1^2}{2}+\frac{(p_2-k\;q_2)^2}{2}   ,\qquad  k\in\mathbb{R}.$$

I know that the hamiltonian isnt explicitly dependent on time so $H$ is a motion constant.
But, is the hamiltonian equal to energy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does Hamiltonian equals to energy of the system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283165/)

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/151680/

Comment: What definition of energy do you use?