# Physical interpretation of the canonical scalar product in linear dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, complex-systems, coupled-oscillators, linear-systems

Consider a unforced, undamped, linear mechanical system with a finite number of degrees of freedom. Its (second order) dynamical equations can be gathered in a matrix equation

$$M\ddot X + K X=0$$

Three natural scalar products appear:

- The canonical scalar product $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto X^\top Y$
- The scalar product which stems from the kinetic energy: $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto X^\top M Y$
- The scalar product which stems from the potential energy: $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto X^\top K Y$

If written in the first order form the ODE leads, in the same spirit, to:

1. Canonical scalar product $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}\mapsto X^\top Y$
2. Scalar product from the quadratic form of the energy $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}\mapsto X^\top\begin{bmatrix} K & 0 \\ 0 & M \end{bmatrix} Y$

**Question** While the physical meaning of the scalar product for the energy is obvious, how can the canonical scalar product be interpreted?

**Edit** The answer could be that there is none (what I tend to believe), but it should be supported.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78500/2451

Comment: @XiaodongQi: $Y$ does not have to be defined, it is a variable. You can even take $Y=X$ if you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is being asked. $(\dot X, X).diag(M,K).(\dot X, X)$ is the total energy or Hamiltonian. $(\dot X, X).diag(M,-K).(\dot X, X)$ would be the Lagrangian. What does "interpreted" here mean?

Comment: @user2309840 Well, as you said the meaning of the Hamiltonian is direct; the Lagrangian is the difference between kinetic and potential energy. Both do not depend on the basis choice. Can $(\dot X,X)^\top.(\dot X,X)$ be understood in a simple way? By "physical interpretation" I basically mean _not depending on the choice of a basis_.

Answer (score 2):

From the physics perspective, there is a dimensional (or unit analysis) problem with the inner product on ${\mathbb R}^{2n}$ of the form $(\dot X, X)^T.(\dot X, X)$.  Naively, I'm adding a velocity squared to a position squared, and the units are not compatible.  Or maybe, if I'm allowed to trade $\dot X$ for momentum $P$, then I'm adding momentum squared to position squared which also doesn't make any sense.  To make sense of this inner product, I need to introduce some kind of scale which will make the units compatible -- much the way inserting the matrices $M$ and $K$ will perform the same job and give me an interpretation in terms of the total energy.

A more natural inner product on ${\mathbb R}^{2n}$ in this case involves a [symplectic bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space).  In the two dimensional case, such an inner product would involve the matrix
$$
\omega = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
This inner product, from a quantum mechanics perspective anyway, has a physical interpretation in terms of the commutator of position and momentum.

Back to classical mechanics, writing the ODE using a Hamiltonian, e.g. $H = (p^2 / m + m x^2)/2$, naturally involves this symplectic bilinear form. The ODE in first order form becomes
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = -\dot p \ , \\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} = \dot x \ .
$$
which I can then recast as
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial Z} = - \omega \cdot \dot Z
$$
where I have defined $Z = (x,p)$.  There is tons of literature on symplectic forms and classical mechanics, for example [Arnold's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387968903).

Comment: Interesting. What about $\dot X^t\cdot \dot X$, there is no unit problem but can it still be associated to a physical concept (i don't think so)? Btw, the link to wikipedia is not working.

Comment: Sure, why not?  $\dot X^t \cdot \dot X$ should be the velocity squared (or the momentum squared if you multiply by a mass).

Comment: OK so $\dot X^\top\cdot M\cdot \dot  X$ is the double of the kinetic energy, while $m\dot X^\top \cdot m\dot X$ is norm of the momentum squared, both have a "meaning" right?

Comment: I'm happy to say yes to that.

Comment: Now how I feel my question was so stupid... it means your answer was useful!