# Equilibrium points in lagrangian mechanics with generalized potentials

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, potential, velocity, equilibrium, complex-systems

I understand the way i calculate equilibrium points when i have a lagrangian without mixed terms (with coordinates and velocities multiplied), thinking of the coordinate dependent part of the lagrangian as a  potential $V$ of a real force; how do i proceed when i have mixed terms?

Answer (score 0):

1. Given an [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) 1st-order Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q})$, the Euler-Lagrange equations are an autonomous 2nd-order (coupled) ODEs $f(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q})=0$.
2. An [equilibrium point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_point) $q_{(0)}$ satisfies $f(q_{(0)},0,0)=0$.
3. To check if the equilibrium point $q_{(0)}$ is stable or not, expand the position variable $q(t)=q_{(0)}+u(t)$,
   and consider the linearized theory, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/78568/2451).