# Are there any "linear" lagrangian systems of interest for which an analytic solution is not obvious?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, complex-systems, linear-systems, linearized-theory

Out of curiosity, I am interested in Lagrangian dynamical systems that can be expressed in a "linear" manner. By this, I mean that their Lagrangian can be expressed, quadratically, as

$$L = \frac{1}{2} \dot q^T M \dot q - \frac12 q^T K q^T,$$

where $q \in \mathbb{R}^n$; $M$ and $K$ are symmetric, positive-definite, $n$-dimensional square matrices with constant coefficients; the overdot denotes time differentiation.

One example of such a system is the linearized double pendulum which is simply a double pendulum where one assumes small angles during motion (see for example https://math24.net/double-pendulum.html).

Usually, it is easy to obtain the exact solution for this kind of system (as for the linearized double pendulum). So I wonder if there exists any other example of true technical/scientific interest? Particularly, is there a similar example where the analytic solution is not obvious and requires the use of numerical methods?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Any "linear" system is considered to be exactly solvable, but the double pendulum is decidedly *not* exactly soluble - instead, one has to linearise (i.e. approximate) the equations of motion and handle the nonlinearity perturbatively.

Comment: @catalogue_number What you say is true. The nonlinear double pendulum has to be linearized in order to be exactly solvable. What I wonder is if there are other systems of the sort, with physical meaning and of scientific interest, that are linear: either by nature or that lead to interesting applications when linearized. Also, I am not a specialist, so I was not sure that every linear system is exactly solvable.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78500/2451

Answer (score 3):

Almost every linear system derived from a Lagrangian of this form has an exact solution. To find it, we use the fact that all systems of this form have a set of [normal coordinates](https://www.physics.purdue.edu/%7Eclarkt/Courses/Physics410/Selected%20Lecture%20Notes/Phys410V.pdf) $\xi_i$.  These coordinates are related to the original coordinates $q_i$ by an invertible linear transformation, and when the Lagrangian is written in terms of them, the matrices $M$ and $K$ become diagonal:
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \mu_2 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \mu_n \end{bmatrix}
\qquad
K = \begin{bmatrix} \kappa_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \kappa_2 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \kappa_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
This means that the equations of motion for the coordinates $\xi_i$ are simply
$$
\mu_i \ddot{\xi}_i = - \kappa_i \xi_i \quad \Rightarrow \quad \xi_i(t) = A_i \cos (\omega_i t + \delta_i)
$$
with $\omega_i = \sqrt{\kappa_i/\mu_i}$.

So the method to solve the original system is as follows:

- Find the linear transformation between the original coordinates $q_i$ and the normal coordinates $\xi_i$.
- Find the forms of the matrices $M$ and $K$ when the Lagrangian is expressed in terms of these coordinates.
- Write down the general solutions for the $\xi_i$ coordinates.
- Use the inverse relationship between the $q_i$ and the $\xi_i$ to write down the general solution for the original coordinates.

The caveats in this procedure are as follows:

- The original matrix $M$ must be *positive definite*, which is equivalent to saying that the kinetic energy of the system is never negative, and is only zero when all the velocities are zero.  This is always true for interesting systems in classical point-particle mechanics.  This guarantees that all of the quantities $\mu_i$ in the diagonalized matrix are strictly positive.
- In the case where the matrix $K$ is not positive definite, there will exist $\kappa_i$ quantities that are either zero or negative.  In these cases, the corresponding coordinate $\xi_i$ will grow linearly or exponentially, instead of oscillating sinusoidally.  The exact solution still exists, and the above-described procedure still works;  it just ends up having a different form in the end.

The procedure for constructing the normal coordinates for a given system is too long & involved to present here, but it can be found in most upper-level classical mechanics textbooks (Taylor, Morin, Thornton & Marion, Goldstein, etc.)  It is a slight generalization of the idea of [diagonalizing a matrix.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixDiagonalization.html)

**EDIT:**  You ask specifically about whether such problems "require the use of numerical methods".  The diagonalization procedure mentioned above does involve finding the roots of an $n$-order polynomial, and [it may not be possible to find a closed-form expression for these roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) when $n \geq 5.$  In such cases, numerical root-finding techniques might have a role.  However, the solution to this system will always be a linear combination of sinusoids, linear functions, and exponentials;  so it will generally not be necessary to employ a numerical ODE solver to understand the behavior of the system.

Comment: This procedure is not exactly a very easy one. So should I assume that there are many linearized lagrangian systems of interest for which the exact solution is not obvious?

Comment: I suppose?  You definitely don't need a full-on Runge-Kutta ODE solver to solve the Euler-Lagrange equations, if that's what you mean by "numerical techniques". The solution will always be a combination of sinusoids with some frequencies, and all you need to do is to find the frequencies (from the matrices $M$ and $K$) and the amplitudes & phases (from the initial conditions.) That said, finding these frequencies may need to be done numerically for sufficiently large matrices, so there's a role for numerics in sufficiently complicated systems.

Comment: *"finding these frequencies may need to be done numerically for sufficiently large matrices"*. So by this rationale, would you say that if $M$ and $K$ have sufficiently large dimensions, using a numerical method might be more, let's say practical, than finding the exact solution?

Comment: There might not even be an exact solution.  The diagonalization process involves finding the roots of an *n*th-order polynomial, where $n$ is the number of coordinates in the system. For $n \geq 5$ there are polynomials whose roots [can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Ruffini_theorem) and so you're stuck with numerical approximations to them.  But even in such cases one could imagine writing down an "exact solution" involving cosines with frequencies, amplitudes, and phases that are are only known numerically.  If that makes sense.

Comment: The other important point is that there are no novel behaviors you're ever going to get out of a system like this.  The solution for $q_i(t)$ will *always* be some sum of oscillating sinusoids, linear functions, and exponential functions.  You'll never get polynomial growth or evolution to a singularity in a finite amount of time or something like that.

Comment: I believe that a combination of your comments should be part of your answer. From what I understand, the use of numerical methods to predict the system evolution might be practical for restricted cases where $M$ and $K$ are large. In the beginning, I was simply looking for specific examples but thank you for sharing your insights, they improve my understanding.

Comment: @Meclassic:  Done.